# Error 404 display Issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I need help with Error 404 Display of my website. When i enter a wrong URL i get a Error 500 display. If i change the URL to a page that i'm sure is in the root, i still get this same Error 500 display.

Please where could the problem come from.

Both the .htaccess file and the 404.php are in the same directory ( root )...

Below is the content of my .htaccess file

```
  ErrorDocument 404/church/404.php
```

this is the error in the Apache Error File

```
   [Sat Apr 28 9:10:04] [alert] [client 127.     0. 0.1] C:/wamp/www/church/.                        htaccess: ErrorDocument takes two          arguments, Change responses for HTTP       errors
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space: it should say `ErrorDocument 404 /church/404.php`. (Well, I can't absolutely guarantee that that will work because I don't know what you have in your filesystem, but that's definitely righter than what you have now.)

Comment: Thanks.. I have added the space. but my customised 404 Page is not displaying.

Here's what i have on the screen.


     The Requested URL /church/hhh.php was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the Request......

What does the file system has to do.
I have both of my .htaccess and 404.php in the same directory.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like there isn't a file at `/church/404.php`. How about `ErrorDocument 404 c:/wamp/www/church/404.php`?